# Aside from work done for a force, is there anything else that $\int_C F\cdot\,dr$ can calculate?

Tags: vector-analysis

Aside from the work done by a force $F$, is there anything else that $\int_C F\cdot\,dr$ can calculate?  I heard that it also calculates "circulation." What other things can be mathematically modeled by integrals of this form?

Comment: Since the integral has only one result and that result is the work done, what else do you expect?

Comment: If $F$ is the force vector and $dr$ a distance element, yes. On the other hand, you can find line integrals with different interpretations by changing the function or the space where you're integrating.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : But what if you're integrating along a curve in a space in which each point is some state of an economic system and $F$ and $r$ are some vector-valued variables related to the economy?  I took the question to mean: What other things can be mathematically modeled by integrals of this form?

Comment: I heard that it also calculates "circulation", and yes, What other things can be mathematically modeled by integrals of this form?

Comment: If $F$ is a force and $C$ is the path of a particle, then $\int_C F \cdot dr$ is the definition of work.  If however, instead of interpreting $F$ as force, but instead some other vector field, then there are a plethora of mathematical and physical applications.  [Here](http://www.math24.net/physical-applications-of-line-integrals.html) are some examples of how line integrals are used in basic physics.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that's what I and other friends were looking for